# redux todomvc: cannot understand `mapStateToProps`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Looking into [redux todomvc](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js#L21), still confused by `connect` and [mapStateToProps](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/containers/App.js#L20).

Part of codes in todomvc/src/containers/App.js are:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  todos: state.todos
})
```

`state` is the state in Redux' store. But I am confused that `state` has a `todos` property, which is an Array. The `todos` is reducer, and is function [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/reducers/todos.js#L11) and [here](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/reducers/index.js#L5). Cannot understand what `mapStateToProps` does here still after reading https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md.

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With redux your app state exists together in one object, known as state. When you create a new reducer, you need to include it in the `combineReducers` helper. You can see that happening in this [file](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/85e2368ea9ff9b308fc873921ddf41929638f130/examples/todomvc/src/reducers/index.js). The name of the key you use for each reducer actually ends up being the same name in the state. In this case it's todos. If you created a new reducer for users and included it in the `combineReducers` helper as `users` it would be available as `state.users`.

Comment: state.todos (Array) is the output of reducer function. and `todos` is named after the key name inside `combineReducers`? Am I right? Thanks

Comment: yep, you got it

Answer (score 3):

I'll give it a try. I hope I am succinct enough.

As you correctly see, the "state" is passed in to "mapStateToProps". What this is, is an object that contains your reducers - your "stores" or "states" for each reducer.

If, for example, that second example you posted looked like this.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import todos from './todos'
import products from './products'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  todos,
  products
})

export default rootReducer
```

You now have the "products" state. So your 'state' object that is passed into mapStateToProps, looks like this

```
state = {
  todos,
  products
}
```

because that "combineReducers" functions "combines" all your reducers and basically creates keys under the "state/store" - major app store. Remember, redux creates this idea of one source of truth for your global state. So, by combingReducers, we place these new state objects in your "global state", as keys... that is if you have more than one reducer. More often than  not, you'll have just one. And many times, you might not want "all of your state", maybe just a slice.

So, your component, lets say we did this.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  todos: state.todos,
  products: state.products
})
```

your component now has access to the following:

```
this.props.todos
this.props.products
```

All the mapStateToProps does is makes it convenient for you to access this "global" store/state onto your component by mapping these values onto your component. Basically, it gobbles your component in, adds the props, then spits it back out altered.. with your new values.

Comment: Where is the mapStateToProps function supposed to go? Can I have this at my highest level where they put providers and then be done with it or do you always keep writing this damn thing?

Comment: Hey Michael - I usually put the mapStateToProps in the container component/page -- then hand down to the children components what they need. "I use to put it everywhere" by abstracting out the behavior and just having a middleware that handled it. BUT, having it on every component is a performance hindrance between everytime a state changes, it cascades into every component that might not care about the particular state change. So, what I do now is use it in my "top/parent" component(s), then sprinkle down to my children what they need. Does that answer your question?